# How to give your localhost host a local domain

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat

i would like to know if it was possible to access your Apache server from eclipse with a .com instead of the localhost:8080

I.E : www.insertlinkhere.net < and it would redirect it to the tomcat server.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand the question. You would just like to access tomcat like www.mysite.com as opposed to localhost:8080?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is go to [No-IP](http://www.noip.com/), then you get a domain and forward it to your localhost on port 8080. That's the one simple way I know.

Be advised, a .com/net/org cost money. But they still have other kinds of free domains you can get.

Answer (score 0):

If you install [nginx](http://nginx.org) you can setup a reverse proxy on your local machine which redirects port 8080 to 80 and then adjust your hosts file to redirect the URL to your local machine

Edit your hosts file `/etc/hosts` or `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` to setup the redirect to your loopback address. Be sure if running windows to run notepad as administrator so you're able to edit the file.

The new entry will look like this in your `hosts` file.

```
127.0.0.1   www.insertlinkhere.net
```

The nginx config will look something like this

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_key sfs$request_uri$scheme;
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080/;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
}
```

**EDIT:** I should add you should also be able to setup a similar reverse proxy in Apache to achieve the same effect. Another alternative would be to adjust your application settings to use port 80 instead of 8080 and then all you would need to adjust is your hosts file to redirect locally. The one issue with this is you would likely need to run eclipse as an administrator to bind to port 80 locally.

Comment: Late reply, i've tried your solution for the nginx and i'm getting an error about permission.


2014/10/05 05:06:03 [emerg] 14056#16196: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions)

Comment: You will probably need to run nginx as administrator. If you are running on Windows right click and run as administrator.

Comment: Well now i've done that and i'm receiving; 2014/10/05 06:12:32 [emerg] 12460#16072: "server_names_hash_bucket_size" directive is not allowed here in C:\Users\Tonton\Downloads\nginx-1.7.6\nginx-1.7.6/conf/nginx.conf:2

Comment: Must i move it in a different folder?

Comment: You can just remove that line. I had that leftover from one of my configs I used for this answer. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

The folder you run it from should not matter.

Comment: Sorry if i annoy you, but i receive the same error message except now it says "server" directive is not allowed.
And for Eclipse, it doesn't allow me to change on port 80

Comment: I think you can probably remove the line with `server_name` and if you get an error from the line starting with `root` you can remove that too. I'm running it on a Mac so I am unable to test all the windows settings.
You will have to edit the hosts files by running notepad as administrator too if you haven't done that yet. You can open the file by switching from *.txt to all files.